Search and replace between digits with regular expression
I want to search with Notepad++ in a subtitle file for "," and ut should be replaced with "." between the digits of the timestamps but not in the rest of the text strings.
Source:
00:01:17,000 --> 00:01:20,000
vor allem aber an Ausläufen, Reitplätzen
und Weideflächen.

At the moment I'm searching with: "," and for the replacing I'm using the regex "\1.\2". But this will change also all other commas between the text strings.

Search-Pattern: [,]
Replace-Pattern: [\1.\2]

Result:
00:01:17.000 --> 00:01:20.000
vor allem aber an Ausläufen. Reitplätzen
und Weideflächen.

How I have to expand the regular expression to replace the commas only between the digits of the timestamps?
What I expect:
00:01:17.000 --> 00:01:20.000
vor allem aber an Ausläufen, Reitplätzen
und Weideflächen.


Like this? \b\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\K,(?=\d\d\d\b) https://regex101.com/r/P5Ghqs/1 and replace with a dot

You could use a bit more specific regex for Notepad++
\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\K,(?=\d{3}\b)

The pattern matches:

\b A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} Match the hours, minutes and seconds part
\K, Forget what is matched so far and then match a comma
(?=\d{3}\b) Positive lookahead, assert 3 digits followed by a word boundary to the right

In the replacement use a dot .
See a regex demo.

Or use 2 capture groups and use those groups in the replacement separated by a dot $1.$2
\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),(\d{3})\b

See another regex demo.

A fully matching pattern with 3 capture groups, where \h+ matches 1 or more horizontal whitespace characters:
\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),(\d{3}\h+-->\h+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),(\d{3})\b

See another regex demo
In the replacement use $1.$2.$3

I would search for the following :
 ^([0-9:]{8}),(\d{3}) --> ([0-9:]{8}),(\d{3})$

And replace it with this :
\1.\2 --> \3.\4

The regex matches the whole time segment definition, first matching a xx:yy:zz part with [0-9:]{8} (eight digits and colons) and putting it in the first group, then the millisecond parts with \d{3} and putting it in the second group. It does the same with the end time whose parts it puts in the third and fourth group.
The replacement pattern refers to these groups and reconstruct the time segment definition with dots instead of commas.

You can actually shrink the (\d{3}) --> ([0-9:]{8}) into (\d{3} --> [0-9:]{8}) and reference it as one group making the replacement shorter.

@WiktorStribiżew true, I'll leave this optimization to OP as it makes the answer a bit less legible
